# event.target points to a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

When a user clicks on a `<li>`-element or on a child element of it, I want to add a class to this `<li>`-element.

This works fine, but for performance enhancement I decided to bind this event to the `<ul>`-element, so unbinding and binding this event is much faster in a list consisting of 1000 `<li>`-elements. The only change I thought I had to make was to replace `this` with `event.target` BUT `event.target` can also refer to a child element of a list item or even to a grandchild.

Is there an easy way to check this target element is part of a list item or do I need to walk the path from `event.target` till I reach a `<li>` element?

This is what I had before I decided to bind an event to the `<ul>` tag, which works but is not fast enough:

```
$('#list li').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).addClass('green');
});
```

And this is what I have now which doesn't work properly, mousedown on a child element doesn't give the `<li>` another classname:

```
$('#list').mousedown(function(event){
    if(event.target.nodeName == 'LI'){
        $(event.target).addClass('green');
    }
});
```

I wonder if my second way to achieve this is faster if there is not a simple solution to check if that target element is part of a list item...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could do all of this with the jQuery **on** tool:

```
$('#list li').on('mousedown', function() {
  $(this).addClass('green');
});
```

You can read about what **on** does here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This is the same as `.mousedown()` except that it accepts newly created elements as well, am I right? If so, it won't help me, still I need to unbind 1000 events instead of 1.

Comment: No, it is not the same as ".mousedown()." Check the documentation - the new "live()' API is doing exactly what you want.

Comment: Oh and note that the built-into-jquery "live()" API is not the same as the older plugin with a similar name. That one would indeed bind event handlers directly to the elements. The new one takes advantage of bubbling, which is what (I think) you're asking for.

Comment: Thank you; I hadn't noticed `.live()` was updated. Anyway, your piece of code still required thousand events. This helped me out eventually: `$('li', $('#list')).live('click', function(e){ ..});`. This requires one event and uses Event Context. If you update your comment I'll accept yours ;)

Comment: Huh?  1000 events?  No, it doesn't require 1000 events. Again, that is **not** how the new "live()" API works.  Yes, the selector references all the "li" elements, but only one event handler is bound, and it's bound to the "body" element.

Comment: Ok, +1, sorry Sir. I'll try to understand how it works and then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Now I get it, thank you! I tested it but .die() didn't work -- then I upgraded jQuery to 1.4.2 and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm very glad that it's working for you!!  jQuery is a really nice library to work with. The API documentation is steadily getting better, too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if there is a LI tag in the parents of the target element.

All of the common frameworks have a way of determining this, it is `up()` in prototype, `ancestor()` in YUI3, and looking at the JQuery docs, it seems like it has a `parent()`, and `parents()` function that you can use for this.

See: http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing

Haven't used JQuery, but it I assume checking for `$(event.target).parent('li')` is the answer.

Comment: Actually you'd probably want ".closest('li')", but again with jQuery the whole problem is already solved by the framework.